# Avoid having pages showing up as 'events' in Google search results

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

We have some pages that are not *events* (they are job postings), but they are showing up as *events* in Google search results. How can we avoid this? The pages do not have structured data, but they include an expiration date (of the job posting), a title, and a description. [Here](https://careerlaunchpad.arcadia.edu/jobs/american-museum-of-natural-history-program-coordinator-online-teacher-education-program/) is one example, and attached is how it shows up as an event in the search results. I have also tested using Google's [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), and it didn't find any item. We do still want the page to show up in search results, but as a regular page and not an event.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess that terms like *American Museum*, *Teacher*, *Education*, *event* and *Program* regularly occur on pages that describe events. Especially the American Museum being both an employer and an event location, could confuse Google.

You could try two things:

1. Add structured data for a job posting. This is a clue for whatever system at Google is working incorrectly that this is not an event. See documentation from [Schema.org](https://schema.org/JobPosting) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/job-posting) for detail.
2. Complain in the [Google Search Community forum](https://support.google.com/websearch/community). Someone from Google might look at it and flag it as a bug.